# Objects vs References

Tags: python, object, pointers, reference

I'm trying to understand the difference between references and objects. Please let me know if I'm not using the right terminology.

Consider the following code:

```py
# SCENARIO 1
a = 1
b = a
a = 3
b  # still 1, no surprises there
```

Also consider the following code:

```py
# SCENARIO 2
class Node:
   def __init__(self, link, value):
       self.link = link
       self.value = value
 
sll = Node(Node(None, 1), 2)
current = sll
current = current.link
current.value = 3
sll.link.value  # updated to 3!
```

I've seen a lot of similarly phrased questions, but I still cannot understand what makes scenarios 1 and 2 different such that in scenario 2 we can update `sll` by manipulating its reference, but we cannot do the same in scenario 1.

Comment: Numbers, strings, booleans, tuples etc. are immutable. Objects such as `Node` (or lists, dicts, etc.) aren't, and everything in Python is passed by reference.

Comment: I don't think this is about immutability. OP can rewrite first example with `a = []; b = a; a = [3]; b` and still receive `[]` even though list is mutable. The actual difference between these snippets, is that in the first example you're redefining `a`, while in the second you're changing state of the object. These are just two different operations.

Comment: Good point. If the OP ran `ssl = Node(Node(None, 2), 3)`, that would make no change to `current`, mutability notwithstanding.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. Every name in Python is a reference to some object. In this case, `a` and `b` are both references to the same `int` object, and `sll` and `current` are both references to the same `Node` object. `current = current.link` makes `current` point to a *different* object, the same one referenced by `sll.link`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **two codes are essentially different**. In scenario 1, yo do just assignments. It would be the same with `Node`s (below I use simple `list` instead):

```py
# SCENARIO 1
a = 1
b = a
a = 3
b  # still 1, no surprises there
```

```py
# SCENARIO 1
a = [1]
b = a
a = [3]
b  # still [1], no surprises there
```

Really does not matter what you use here.

```py
# SCENARIO 2
sll = [1,2]
current = sll
current[0] = 3
sll[0]  # updated to 3!
```

This is because `sll` and `current` are **same objects**. Different names, but the same object, the same place in memory.

You cannot do scenario 2 with `int` and similar, because `int` (and similar types) is immutable and you cannot do anything like `a[0]=...`, `a.value=...`, you simply cannot mutate it. You can mutate a `list` (or a `Node` in OP).